# Disable details/summary

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I use the new `details` tag in combination with a `summary` I would then like to disable the generated input. I thought that

```
<details open disabled>
```

could do the trick, but sadly it doesn't work.

How can one disable the details element?

Comment: Is this html5? Because I've never seen this in other html versions..

Comment: Yes it is indeed HTML5. As always implemented in Chrome (stable, mostly bugfree) first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using the non-existent `disabled` attribute, you can set a click handler on the `<details>` element, and prevent the default event behavior from there. Quick and dirty way is:

```
<details open onclick="return false">
    <summary>Click here</summary>
    <p>content</p>
</details>
```

The proper way to do it would be using `addEventListener`:

```
<details id="mydetails" open>
    <summary>Click here</summary>
    <p>content</p>
</details>

<script>
document.getElementById('mydetails').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8HUZ/1/

To solve the focus problem you mentioned in the comments, add `tabindex="-1"` as an attribute of `<summary>` to prevent it from getting keyboard focus. Please note that I'm not sure if that will work on every browser, and that a `focus` event will still be triggered on click even with the attribute.

Comment: This solves half of the problem. Sadly there still is the issue of the working focus.

Comment: Do you mean the outline style? You can remove that with `summary:focus { outline: none; }​` (or some more specific selector).

Comment: No I mean that it gains keyboard focus. AFAIK not solvable by CSS.

Comment: @LCIDFire You can try `<summary tabindex="-1">` to avoid keyboard focus (it will still fire a focus event on click, though).

Comment: Could you please add the `tabindex` part to your answer. Adding that, it works fine.

Answer (score 19):

A very simple way would be to use only CSS. You can still use the `disabled` attribute or make it a `class` instead if you would prefer. The [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) declaration when set to `none` makes the `summary` tag invisible to mouse (elements below the tag would thus be clickable.) Added `tabindex="-1"` to the `summary` tags for the disabled ones to eliminate keyboard focus.

```
<details open disabled>
  <summary tabindex="-1">click here: [disabled]</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>

<details open class="disabled">
  <summary tabindex="-1">click here: .disabled</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>

<details open>
  <summary>click here: NOT disabled</summary>
  <p>content</p>
</details>

<style>
  details[disabled] summary,
  details.disabled summary {
    pointer-events: none; /* prevents click events */
    user-select: none; /* prevents text selection */
  }
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/joelnagy/pen/MWKNGGp

Comment: Yes! Do not be afraid to leverage standard attributes even if they technically don't apply to an element.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it doesn't require JS. 

Comment: This is only partially correct, as a keyboard user can still open and close it with this solution: you need to put `tabindex="-1"` on the summary element to prevent that.

Comment: @KoenCornelis Thanks for catching that. I updated the code to add `tabindex="-1"`.

Comment: You should set `tabindex="-1"` on the `summary` element (like @koen-cornelis proposed) and not on the `details` element. Otherwise also the content inside the `details` (like links) won't be reachable for keyboard users.

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, one can still reach the content and open the details with ⌘ f (find) and searching for text.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can return false to prevent the default behaviour:

```
<details open="" onclick="return false;">
<p>Hello</p></details>
```

Comment: It's more simple. Thank you guy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but needed an angular 7 solution.  So in my template I set the details tag as follows:

```
<details open (click)="preventAction()">
....
</details>
```

Then wrote the method in my component like so

```
  preventAction(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<details class="mydetails" open>
<summary>Click here</summary>
<p>content</p></details>

$(".mydetails").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();});
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?  Why does this solve the question being asked?